# free() invalid pointer when trying to free a char* and a stuct

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management

Im trying to free the `char* line` before closing the method to avoid having memory allocated in the heap for something that only serves a local purpose every time the method is called. When calling the free() method for the `char* line` im getting this error: `free(): invalid pointer`

EDIT: trying to `free(this_session)` also gives this error: `free(): double free detected in tcache 2`. session is a struct defined in a `.h` like this: `typedef struct session_list *session;`

Im still a beginner developer and im still learning the memory allocation concepts of C, it would be great if someone could explain me why my pointer is no longer valid to be freed up ( im guessing it has something to do with `strtok()`)

```
extern short* validate_1_svc(param *param, struct svc_req *request){
    //return_code static declariert ( auf static angelet ) damit der return nicht die referenz aufm stack ist.
    static RET_CODE return_code;

    FILE *file;
    file = fopen("hashes.txt","r");
    session this_session;

    char *line = malloc(sizeof(char)*256);

    this_session = search_session(sessions, param->id);
    if(this_session == NULL){
        return_code = NO_SESSION_FOUND;
    }else {
        while (fgets(line, 256, file)) {
            char *p;
            if ((p = strchr(line, '\n')) != NULL) {//check exist newline
                *p = '\0';
            } else {
                scanf("%*[^\n]");
                scanf("%*c");//clear upto newline
            }
            line = strtok(line, " ");
            if (strcmp(line, this_session->user) == 0) {
                line = strtok(NULL," ");
                //TODO hash von session id + user&psw erstellen und prüfen
                if (strcmp(line,param->hash) == 0){
                    return_code = OK;
                    break;
                }else{
                    return_code = WRONG_PASSWORD;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(file);
    free(this_session);
    free(line);
    return &return_code;
}
```

Comment: In `line = strtok(line, " ");` and `line = strtok(NULL," ");` you've lost the pointer from the `malloc()` allocation. Save it in another variable - you can only pass a pointer to `free()` that came from `malloc` - not somewhere within the memory block.

Comment: @WeatherVane thanks for the help! if I save the strtok() return on another variable do I also need to free up the space myself ? or can i just do something like this ```char* strtokreturn; ``` and save the strtok() in there ? im trying to figure out how to avoid having the strtok() return on the heap.

Comment: Do this: `char *lptr = malloc(256); char *line = lptr; .... free(lptr);` You need to set `line = lptr` in *every* loop iteration. Otherwise the next `fgets()` will overflow the buffer :)

Comment: @WeatherVane alright will do that thank! in this case ```char* line``` will be placed in the stack and is pointing to the memory allocated on the heap by the ```char *lptr``` ? is this right ?

Comment: regarding: `extern short* validate_1_svc(param *param, struct svc_req *request){`  the 'type' `param` is not defined anywhere in the posted code, so the posted code does not compile!   Please correct this problem.

Comment: OT: regarding: `file = fopen("hashes.txt","r");`  the call to `fopen()` can fail in LOTS AND LOTS of ways.  Always check (!=NULL)  the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  if not successful (==NULL) then call `perror( "fopen to read ... failed" )`.  Since this is not a recoverable error, suggest cleaning up then calling: `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Comment: what type are these `return_code = NO_SESSION_FOUND;` and `return_code = WRONG_PASSWORD;`? Those should be pointers, since your function `validate_1_svc` return value is `short* `

Comment: @sravs those were defined in the .h file. Im doing an assignment für University and we need to use a RPC generated file. the retrun values are working as expected :)

Comment: @user3629249 you are right about the fopen problem, I did not remember to check for failures, thanks for the heads up, will review the code tomorrow again and fix that. 
regarding your post above, "param" is a struct that was defined on a RPC file.